# Asp.net Response.end

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to solve the following problem in my current project.

**Existing**

There is a button on an `aspx` page which has a server side click event. We do some processing in this event based on the selected gridview rows and show a file download dialog to the browser based on selected records.

**Functionality to be changed**

If any records are failed during processing then we want prompt user that “ There are errors for few selected records during processing. Do you want to continue with file download?”

**Approach I tried to solve this problem**

I trigger jquery function from server side `button_click` event to show jquery dialog to inform user that there are errors for a few selected records during processing.

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);`

I call webmethod using Ajax which executes the following code:

```
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "Application/Octet-Stream";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
string.Format("Attachment; FileName={0}", Path.GetFileName(filePath)));
response.WriteFile(filePath);
response.End();
```

**Result**

I got the popup and web method is also executing fine but I am not seeing any file download dialog box in browser. I am suspicious that `response.end` does not work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download a file via AJAX. It has to be form-submit or GET-request via a link-click. `Response.End` works fine: you did **not** just find a bug in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a file via javascript you can do something like this with the file returned by an API endpoint, this code is using an angular call but it can be accomplished without it as well:

```
    // Make an api call with the responseType of blob and do this with the result
    const blob = new Blob([result], { type: result.type });

    if ($window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');// create a new <a> tag element
      downloadLink.attr('href', fileURL);
      downloadLink.attr('download', fileName);
      downloadLink.attr('target', '_self');
      downloadLink[0].click();// call click function
      URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);// revoke the object from URL
    }
```